# Can 2^n be calculated in less than n-1 successive multiplications?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have a question which pertains to the possibility of calculating 2^n, given any n, in less than n-1 successive multiplications.
What could be the best strategy which I could utilize to achieve the same operation by avoiding the task of doing n-1 multiplications? Can this be done in lesser multiplications?
If yes, then how?

-Thanks

Comment: In what language? Most of the programming languages have a `power(x, n)` function.

Comment: And what representation for the output? You can compute the binary representation of `2^n` without any multiplications :-)

Comment: related: [Addition-chain exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation), online tool to calculate [Shortest Addition Chains](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/addition_chain.html).

Comment: the language is not a concern. 
the entire point is to avoid the usage of the exponential operator in most languages. However, I am more of a perl person. C is also fine.

Answer (score 9):

Yes 2^n can be computed in Log(n) multiplication, this is known as [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Answer (score 9):

For (2^n) and (n>=0) you might use bitwise shifting: **(2^n) is (1 << n)**